# Independent cycles in permutation

Tags: java, c++, permutation

I have problems creating a function that takes permutation as an input and prints out independent cycles(in cycle notation).
I will appreciate any help.

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6             
        5 3 2 6 4 1
```

Output:

`(1 5 4 6)(2 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the first number (digit), follow the mappings until you're back to the first number. That's your first cycle.

Then start with the next number that hasn't been visited yet, and repeat the process.

Keep repeating until all numbers have been visited.

```
↓             Start at first number
1 2 3 4 5 6     1
5 3 2 6 4 1

*       ↓     1 maps to 5:
1 2 3 4 5 6     1 → 5
5 3 2 6 4 1

*     ↓ *     5 maps to 4:
1 2 3 4 5 6     1 → 5 → 4
5 3 2 6 4 1

*     * * ↓   4 maps to 6:
1 2 3 4 5 6     1 → 5 → 4 → 6
5 3 2 6 4 1

*     * * *   6 maps to 1:
1 2 3 4 5 6     1 → 5 → 4 → 6 → 1
5 3 2 6 4 1     First cycle complete
```

```
* ↓   * * *   Start at first unvisited number:
1 2 3 4 5 6     2
5 3 2 6 4 1

* * ↓ * * *   2 maps to 3:
1 2 3 4 5 6     2 → 3
5 3 2 6 4 1

* * * * * *   3 maps to 2:
1 2 3 4 5 6     2 → 3 → 2
5 3 2 6 4 1     Second cycle complete
```

```
All digits visited, result:
  1 → 5 → 4 → 6 and 2 → 3  ⇒  (1546)(23)
```

Now you just need to write the code for this, in whichever language you prefer.

*Hint:* You will need 3 arrays, one for first set of numbers, one for second set of numbers, and an array to track which numbers have been visited.

You'll also need something to capture the result, e.g. a `StringBuilder` if you use Java.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a Java solution that supports negative and multi-digit numbers, with full input validation:

```
private static String findCycles(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The sets cannot be empty");
    if (a.length != b.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sets must have same size: " + a.length + " != " + b.length);
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> numIdx = IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> a[i], Function.identity(),
                                      (i1, i2) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate numbers not allowed: " + a[i1]); },
                                      TreeMap::new));
    if (! IntStream.of(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()).equals(numIdx.keySet()))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sets must consist of the same numbers");
    String separator = (numIdx.firstKey() < 0 || numIdx.lastKey() > 9 ? " " : "");
    BitSet used = new BitSet(a.length);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int idx; (idx = used.nextClearBit(0)) < a.length; ) {
        StringJoiner cycle = new StringJoiner(separator, "(", ")");
        do {
            used.set(idx);
            cycle.add(String.valueOf(a[idx]));
            idx = numIdx.get(b[idx]);
        } while (! used.get(idx));
        result.append(cycle.toString());
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
// Example from question:
System.out.println(findCycles(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                              new int[] { 5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1 }));

// Examples from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation:
System.out.println(findCycles(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
                              new int[] { 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1, 3 }));
System.out.println(findCycles(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
                              new int[] { 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3 }));
System.out.println(findCycles(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                              new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 }));

// Support for negative and multi-digit values:
System.out.println(findCycles(new int[] { -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 },
                              new int[] { 0, 5, -5, 10, 20, 15 }));
```

*Output*

```
(1546)(23)
(146837)(2)(5)
(14625837)
(1)(24)(3)
(-5 0 5)(10)(15 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will show you (one of many) possible solution and a complete working example in C++.

We just follow the path through the 2 permutations. We need to take care for **independent** cycles, prevent double cycles and need to avoid infinit looping through cycles.

The secret is to select the correct container type. I use 2. For a cyle, I use a `std::unordered_set`. This can contain only unique elements. With that, an infinite cycle will be prevented. For example: 0,1,3,0,1,3,0,1,3 . . . is not possible, because each digit can only be once in the container. That will stop the way through the permutations again and again. As soon as we see a number that is already in a cycle, we stop.

All found cycles will be stored in the second container type: A `std::set`. The `std::set` can also contain only unique values and, the values are ordered.

Because we store complex data in the `std::set`, we create a custom comparator for it. We need to take care that the `std::set` will not contain 2 double entries.

And double would be in our case also 0,1,3 and 1,3,0. In our custom comparator, we will first copy the 2 sets into a std::vector and sort the std::vectors. This will make 1,3,0 to 0,1,3. Then we can easily detect doubles.

In the below example code, I do always only store a value from the first permutation in the cycle. The 2nd is used as helper, to find the index of the next value to evaluate.

Please see the complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

// Make reading easier and define some alies names
using MyType = int;
using Cycle = std::unordered_set<MyType>;
using Permutation = std::vector<MyType>;
using Permutations = std::vector<Permutation>;

// We do not want to have double results. 
// A double cyle is also a Cycle with elements in different order
// So define custom comparator functor for our resulting set
struct Comparator {
    bool operator () (const Cycle& lhs, const Cycle& rhs) const {
        // Convert the unordered_sets to vectors
        std::vector<MyType> v1(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
        std::vector<MyType> v2(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
        // Sort them 
        std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
        // Compare them
        return v1 < v2;
    }
};
// Resulting cycles
using Cycles = std::set<Cycle, Comparator>;

int main() {

    // The source data
    Permutations perms2 = {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6},
        {5,3,2,6,4,1} };

    // Lamda to find the index of a given number in the first permutation
    auto findPos = [&perms2](const MyType& m) {return std::distance(perms2[0].begin(), std::find(perms2[0].begin(), perms2[0].end(), m)); };

    // Here we will store our resulting set of cycles
    Cycles resultingCycles{};

    // Go through all single elements of the first permutation
    for (size_t currentColumn = 0U; currentColumn < perms2[0].size(); ++currentColumn) {

        // This is a temporary for a cycle that we found in this loop
        Cycle trialCycle{};

        // First value to start with
        size_t startColumn = currentColumn;

        // Follow the complete path through the 2 permutations
        for (bool insertResult{ true }; insertResult; ) {

            // Insert found element from the first permutation in the current cycle
            const auto& [newElement, insertOk] = trialCycle.insert(perms2[0][startColumn]);

            // Find the index of the element under the first value (from the 2nd permutation)
            startColumn = findPos(perms2[1][startColumn]);

            // Check if we should continue (Could we inster a further element in our current cycle)
            insertResult = insertOk;
        }

        // We will only consider cycles with a length > 1
        if (trialCycle.size() > 1) {
            // Store the current temporary cycle as an additional result.
            resultingCycles.insert(trialCycle);
        }
    }

    // Show result. Simple output
    std::cout << "\n\nFound Cycles:\n\n";
    // Go through all found cycles
    for (const Cycle& c : resultingCycles) {
        // Print an opening brace
        std::cout << "(";
        // Handle the comma delimiter
        std::string delimiter{};

        // Print all integer values of the cycle
        for (const MyType& m : c) {
            std::cout << delimiter << m;
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        std::cout << ")";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, guys thanks a lot for ur solutions but I have to make it simpler. I should use 2d dynamic array and probably more 1d dynamic arrays as well because I shoud get the input from the user.Thank you in advance.