# How to implement an unordered data structure using set?

Tags: c++

I want to build an unordered set for my Face structure, that is

```
class myFace
{
public:
    //the three points
    int u;
    int v;
    int k;
    myFace() = default;
    myFace(int u, int v, int k) : u(u), v(v), k(k) {}

    bool operator< (const myFace& e) const
    {
        bool result = true;
        min(u, v, k);
        if ((u == e.u && v == e.v && k == e.k) ||
            (u == e.u && v == e.k && k == e.v) ||
            (u == e.v && v == e.u && k == e.k) ||
            (u == e.v && v == e.k && k == e.u) ||
            (u == e.k && v == e.u && k == e.v) ||
            (u == e.k && v == e.v && k == e.u))
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

I want to make sure that:

```
set<myFace> con;
myFace f1(1,2,3);
myFace f2(2,3,1);
myFace f3(3,1,2);

con.insert(f1);
con.insert(f2);
con.insert(f3);
cout << con.size() << endl;
```

the output should be 1.
Since f1,f2,f3 are same.

Or we can just say how to implement a set for 3 unordered elements, that is 123,132,213,231,312,321 are all same.

Comment: There's something very important that's missing from your question, and that would be an actual question. You have described your goals, but you seem to have left out a specific C++ question. "How to implement (something very generic)" is not really a specific C++ question. What exactly is the specific problem you have when you attempt to implement your set, in the manner you've described?

Comment: Put them into a vector or array, sort and just compare vectors

Comment: Btw your comparator would not work anyway - you need to implement relevance operator like `>` or `<`, you implemented `==`. You may consider `std::unordered_set` which requires `==`

Comment: What are the actual requirement for the unorderedness of the data structure?

Comment: You are implementing `operator<`, not `operator==`. Your `operator<` clearly doesn't model a strict weak ordering as it should and what is `min(u, v, k);` supposed to do?

Comment: just unordered set for 3 elements@UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 1):

The secret is, to use the correct Comparator for your class and give it to the set. I used a similar approach for sets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807955/independent-cycles-in-permutation/59808381#59808381).

I adapted this solution and created the below example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct myFace
{
    //the three points
    int u;
    int v;
    int k;
    myFace() = default;
    myFace(int u, int v, int k) : u(u), v(v), k(k) {}
};


struct Comparator {
    bool operator () (const myFace& lhs, const myFace& rhs) const {
        // Convert the structs to vectors
        std::vector<int> v1 = { lhs.u, lhs.v, lhs.k };
        std::vector<int> v2 = { rhs.u, rhs.v, rhs.k };
        // Sort them 
        std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
        // Compare them
        return v1 < v2;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<myFace, Comparator> con;

    myFace f1(1, 2, 3);
    myFace f2(2, 3, 1);
    myFace f3(3, 1, 2);

    con.insert(f1);
    con.insert(f2);
    con.insert(f3);

    std::cout << con.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how many elements OP plans to have but this solution is quite inefficient - creating vectors on the fly every time.

Comment: @Slava: Yes, I absoultely agree. I would never put in productive code. But I would also not create a struct with 3 ints. I would use a std::array or similar. I guess that this is more or less example code.

Comment: I found that use set can achieve the goal:
```
set<int> face;
face.insert(1);
face.insert(2);
face.insert(3);

set<int> face2;
face2.insert(2);
face2.insert(1);
face2.insert(3);

set<int> face3;
face3.insert(3);
face3.insert(1);
face3.insert(2);

set<set<int>> faces;

faces.insert(face);
faces.insert(face2);
faces.insert(face3);
cout << "----" << endl;
cout << faces.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that use set can achieve the goal: implementing a set for 3 unordered elements, that is 123,132,213,231,312,321 are all same.

```
set<int> face;
face.insert(1);
face.insert(2);
face.insert(3);

set<int> face2;
face2.insert(2);
face2.insert(1);
face2.insert(3);

set<int> face3;
face3.insert(3);
face3.insert(1);
face3.insert(2);

set<set<int>> faces;

faces.insert(face);
faces.insert(face2);
faces.insert(face3);
cout << "----" << endl;
cout << faces.size() << endl;
```